# Change to URL and ReWrite rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have recently been making use off the htaccess file to create rewrites.

Everything works well, but have made a recent change to include a category name followed by the product, like this:

```
http://localhost/Limestone_Tiles/products/Antalya_Blanc.html
```

It just used to be:

```
http://localhost/products/Antalya_Blanc.html
```

When everything worked ok. The rewrite rules where as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*).html$ product_details.php?&furl=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/images/(.*)$ images/$1
RewriteRule ^products/picture_upload/(.*)$ picture_upload/$1
RewriteRule ^products/thumbnail.php(.*)$ thumbnail.php$1
```

So to accommodate the new change I have changed the rewrite rules as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*).html$ product_details.php?&furl=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/images/(.*)$ images/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/picture_upload/(.*)$ picture_upload/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/thumbnail.php(.*)$ thumbnail.php$1
```

Now this kind of works because

```
http://localhost/Limestone_Tiles/products/Antalya_Blanc.html
```

Will load, but none of the images do - which does not make sense to me when the page does? Why don't the images?

If I change the rewrite rule to:

RewriteRule ^Limestone_Tiles/products/images/(.*)$ images/$1

The images will load for that particular category!

If I put the image url into the browser:

```
http://localhost/Limestone_Tiles/products/images/face.png
```

I get the follow message:

The requested URL /images/Limestone_Tiles was not found on this server.

Which is also odd as /images/Limestone_Tiles isn't the Url I have just pasted into the address bar.

Perhaps my rewrite rule is incorrect still?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your rules have groupings that backreference **the first grouped match** and not the match you really want. Say, given this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*).html$ product_details.php?&furl=$1 [NC,L]
```

And this URL:

```
http://localhost/Limestone_Tiles/products/Antalya_Blanc.html
```

The rewritten URI will be: `/product_details.php?&furl=Limestone_Tiles`

Whereas before, with the older rule, it would have been rewritten to: `/product_details.php?&furl=Antalya_Blanc`

If that's your intended behavior, then that's fine, except it's breaking the image rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/images/(.*)$ images/$1
```

The `$1` backreferences the first grouped match `(.*)`, the one *before* `/products/images/`, and not the actual image. It needs to be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/images/(.*)$ images/$2
```

You're probably better off changing the HTML content and fixing this image stuff there as opposed to creating a rewrite rule to try to correct it. You could try adding this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Fantastic - that worked a great! Shall look into your advise too. Many thanks